# uncaught referenceerror calculate is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onChange

Tags: javascript, html

The error I am getting is in the title. (uncaught referenceerror calculate is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onChange) This works if I run it along from notepad++, but when I run it within the website, I get that error. Would anyone be able to shed some light on this? Any help is appreciated.

```html
<p style="text-align: center;"><strong>CBD %</strong></p>
<input id="box1" type="number" value="5" onchange="calculate()"/>
<p style="text-align: center;"><strong>Bottle size (ml)</strong></p>
<input id="box2" type="number" value="100" onchange="calculate()"/>
<p style="text-align: center;"><strong>Calculated value</strong></p>
<input id="result" type="number" value="500" />

<script>
    function calculate() {
 
     var myBox1 = document.getElementById('box1').value; 
        var myBox2 = document.getElementById('box2').value;
        var result = document.getElementById('result'); 
        var myResult = myBox1 * myBox2;
  
        document.getElementById('result').value = myResult;

    }
</script>
```

Screenshot of console:

[image]

Comment: Looks like it has little to do with the code you've shared here, but rather something else, considering the other errors displayed in your console.

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script>
    function calculate() {
 
     var myBox1 = document.getElementById('box1').value; 
        var myBox2 = document.getElementById('box2').value;
        var result = document.getElementById('result'); 
        var myResult = myBox1 * myBox2;
  
        document.getElementById('result').value = myResult;

    }
 } //<---- unwanted character
</script>
```

```html
<p style="text-align: center;"><strong>CBD %</strong></p>
<input id="box1" type="number" value="5" onchange="calculate()"/>
<p style="text-align: center;"><strong>Bottle size (ml)</strong></p>
<input id="box2" type="number" value="100" onchange="calculate()"/>
<p style="text-align: center;"><strong>Calculated value</strong></p>
<input id="result" type="number" value="500" />
```

see if an unwanted character is in the script it cause that error. maybe check that [image]

Comment: if thats just a snippet of the entire code then the problem might be on the other part of the html that snippet is in.

Comment: There's a link at the bottom of the post now

Comment: cause the problem isn't there, there is something maybe an unfinished tag, or an unwanted character, that is preventing it from seeing the function calcFunc()

Comment: That's all my code, but it is a blog post on a wp site

Comment: can i have a link to see it?

Comment: Only staff can see it at the moment since the post isn't released, also calcfunc is just what I changed calculation() to, to prevent any collisions with built in functions

Comment: oh so thats probobly the problem. maybe when it gets release its going to work. Try using inspect element if you could see your script there.